# Carrying dates as the Unix Epoch timestamp

Tags: spring, rest, date, time, timestamp

Quite some time ago I used to work on the specific project using Spring on the backend. The system supposed to work across multiple timezones. Therefore it was decided to use integer values (Long) to store and transfer dates between backend and the web app. As I remember the main reason was to simplify and minimize work with timezones since the timestamp will always represent exact time and we always able to retrieve Date from it without worrying of incorrect timezone (the user's browser will apply proper timezone).

At that time I was little occupied with architecture, as I was only a junior. But since then I have not seen any application of this practice, and I can not find anything on the Internet.

I know there are some cases when we do not need to rely on time zones, for example when I travel to different country I don't want my alarm clock to be changed according to the new timezone. But I still want my reminder to notify me when I need to make an important call at the right time.
I believe the second case is much more common in the software.

Therefore I wanted to know is there any real benefit of using numeric timestamps?

I see at least two potential benefits:

- Less hassle with the timezones (especially for the less experienced devs who can be confused at times working with dates)
- Less data is transferred through the REST (?)

Downsides:

- We have to extract Date value every time to process or display it (this can be automated using most of the frontend frameworks)
- Database values and server debugging is not that self-evident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underneath the scenes of DATE types in databases and higher-level languages, there is always *some* version of a relative date offset and resolution.  In example:

- DOS used 1 January 1980 with 10ms,
- COBOL assumed 1 January 1601 with 1s resolution
- UNIX and its ilk just happened to chose 1 Jan 1970 Midnight GMT.

Benefits of using a numeric and not interpreted numeric in your data storage is arguably (but subjective) easier date arithmetic.  **For TZ-heavy stuff like airline scheduling/logistics relying on the numeric (vs date type) as the numeric native allows one to keep consistency without date type function conversions despite TZs as well as politically-arbitrary DST adjustments**.  Because, the [Uniform Time Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Time_Act) is the *furthest* thing from being uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this really depends on the designated use of that value. It would probably make more sense to expose the timestamp value if you expect a technical usage, and [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) if you expect any other usage. For majority of usages they would probably be synonymous (watch out for leap seconds). They both refer to a fixed point in time.

Exposing the dates as ISO 8601 strings is definitely easier for debugging and for human eyes. You know straight away, which point in time it is.

UNIX timestamps historically also had a flaw of being restricted to the size of integer values. In 64 bit architecture this is usually no longer an issue, but for backwards compatibility strings would be a better option.

I would definitely not recommend to expose the dates through an API in the local time zones. Such values are usually ambiguous and unreliable. They are good for humans, but not good for anything else. Consider daylight saving time for example. Some periods in time exist twice, and some hours do not exist at all.